# How to draw a sinusoidal tube?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'd like to draw a sinusoidal tube with an arrowhead. The piece that is connected to the arrowhead must be a straight tube, but the rest must be sinusoidal tube (for example, from $0$ to $6\pi$ a sinusoidal tube and from $6\pi$ to $7$ a straight tube + arrowhead). I have no idea how to modify the following code to include a sinusoidal part.

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.1], 
Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}}, 0.09]]}, Boxed -> False]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 6 Pi}] /. 
  Line[x_] :> {Red, Tube[x, 0.09]},
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0, 0}, {x, 6 Pi, 7 Pi}] /. 
  Line[x_] :> {Red, Arrowheads[.1], Arrow[Tube[x, 0.09]]},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Axes -> False,
 Boxed -> False
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[.1], 
  Arrow[Tube[Table[{x, 0, If[x <= 6 Pi, Sin @ x, 0]}, {x, 0, 7 Pi, Pi/32}], 0.09]]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]